# How can I allow out of stock product to checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, inventory

Is there any solution available by which I can allow customer to checkout out of stock products in magento ?

Answer (score 4):

There is an option available in admin.

Just go to your manage product page and in inventory tab you can find **Backorders** dropdown, choose allow quantity below 0 option and save, now customer can order out of stock product also.